# Get a change of $50

Tags: word-usage, american-english

Suppose I only have a $100 bill and I bought something that costs around $50. So I get $50 back.  What will be a natural way to express that?

> I got a change of $50 back. 
>    (I mean: I got $50 back, maybe in change or a $50 bill.)

Does it sound natural?

Answer (score 2):

One simple way of saying it is
"*I got $50 change from a $100 bill"*

Comment: You can say "I got $50 change back".

Comment: I like the suggestion by @MichaelH better than the one in the answer. As for the sentence in this answer, it sounds like the speaker asked someone to break a $100 bill and was short-changed fifty dollars.

Comment: @J.R.♦  Shouldn't it be put as "I got $50 change **for** a $100 bill" in such a scenario? As is, it sounds fine imo: "The meal left me with not much change from $200."

Comment: @MvLog - It's a little hard to guess exactly what I'd say, because, in day-to-day conversation I don't normally report how much I paid for something, nor how much I got back in change. If asked to provide a "natural" way to say it, though, I'd offer this: _I gave them a hundred dollars and got fifty back in change._

Answer (score 1):

"Change", meaning "money given to someone because they paid for something that cost less than the amount they gave", is a non-count (mass) noun. So we do not say "a change". Using the example given, we could say, for example, "I got change of $50 back", or "I got $50 change back".

[Change](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/change)

Answer (score 1):

**I got fifty dollars back (in change).** [after a transaction: various bills]
OR
**I got a fifty back (in change)**. [that means a fifty dollar bill]

I took the trouble of writing this out so you can see how to actually say it. The word change above is optional.

- My change was a fifty-dollar bill.
- My change was fifty dollars.

Comment: Doesn't "in change' refer to " coins"?  Or can it mean dollar bills in this context?

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish Not at all. Change can refer to coins or bills.

Comment: And here: You bought an item worth $90. And you pais $100. So the shopkeeper is offering you a $10 bill but you ask "Can I get $10 in change,  please". So if it can mean "bills",  won't it sound confusing? So will "in" sound natural in this context?

Comment: @It'saboutEnglish Like I said, change can be in bills or coins. It is not confusing. To ask for coins or bills IN change.